# Python/pandas and marking "viewed" as TRUE across sessions

Tags: python, pandas

I have some web analytics logs (~1.5 million rows) with date, user id, session id and "views"...let's pretend they are video views. The dataframe looks like this:

```
          date  user_id            session_id  video_views
0   2015-01-01        1  ZzwDgWjzGAUzEDxazfYL            3
1   2015-01-01        2  bH6sC43TrWX5GR85Y3Qc            0
2   2015-01-01        3  FY4zGauPwrfpvezreV7b            2
3   2015-01-01        4  uNwkvSMkz2kTNcYdjUXu            0
4   2015-01-02        1  TGPuDh5LxAN5chuKH7yZ            0
5   2015-01-02        2  FQVgJuKGuRnkMDaXFFLC            0
6   2015-01-02        3  ubDSttTCGvGrJnN4Kerk            3
7   2015-01-02        4  zqrkkm8rNb6dfXyVxEYV            0
8   2015-01-03        1  aCTpmLG7vfD6saq6P7Tv            1
9   2015-01-03        2  F9UYUjnVgW9XMGzYUvRu            0
10  2015-01-03        3  RcmF6Rjk3NVyrejjhhDy            0
11  2015-01-03        4  Fy9bw2xTxLpLRTP7TCV9            0
```

I want to create a column that simply shows whether or not that user has ever viewed a video across any sessions, like this:

```
          date  user_id            session_id  video_views  viewed
0   2015-01-01        1  ZzwDgWjzGAUzEDxazfYL            3       1
1   2015-01-01        2  bH6sC43TrWX5GR85Y3Qc            0       0
2   2015-01-01        3  FY4zGauPwrfpvezreV7b            2       1
3   2015-01-01        4  uNwkvSMkz2kTNcYdjUXu            0       0
4   2015-01-02        1  TGPuDh5LxAN5chuKH7yZ            0       1
5   2015-01-02        2  FQVgJuKGuRnkMDaXFFLC            0       0
6   2015-01-02        3  ubDSttTCGvGrJnN4Kerk            3       1
7   2015-01-02        4  zqrkkm8rNb6dfXyVxEYV            0       0
8   2015-01-03        1  aCTpmLG7vfD6saq6P7Tv            1       1
9   2015-01-03        2  F9UYUjnVgW9XMGzYUvRu            0       0
10  2015-01-03        3  RcmF6Rjk3NVyrejjhhDy            0       1
11  2015-01-03        4  Fy9bw2xTxLpLRTP7TCV9            0       0
```

So, users 1 and 3 have viewed videos, whereas users 2 and 4 have not.

The dtype for this additional column can be categorical or boolean. I just need to add a marker to each session showing whether or not at the *user* level this person has viewed a video during any sessions.

Here are some things you can copy/paste to recreate the original dataframe.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=",",parse_dates=True,names=['date','user_id','session_id','video_views'])

"""
2015-01-01,001,ZzwDgWjzGAUzEDxazfYL,3
2015-01-01,002,bH6sC43TrWX5GR85Y3Qc,0
2015-01-01,003,FY4zGauPwrfpvezreV7b,2
2015-01-01,004,uNwkvSMkz2kTNcYdjUXu,0
2015-01-02,001,TGPuDh5LxAN5chuKH7yZ,0
2015-01-02,002,FQVgJuKGuRnkMDaXFFLC,0
2015-01-02,003,ubDSttTCGvGrJnN4Kerk,3
2015-01-02,004,zqrkkm8rNb6dfXyVxEYV,0
2015-01-03,001,aCTpmLG7vfD6saq6P7Tv,1
2015-01-03,002,F9UYUjnVgW9XMGzYUvRu,0
2015-01-03,003,RcmF6Rjk3NVyrejjhhDy,0
2015-01-03,004,Fy9bw2xTxLpLRTP7TCV9,0
"""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) the 'user_id' select the 'video_views' column and call [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) and pass the function 'sum' and test if this is greater than `0`, this will return a boolean series, which you may want or if you prefer you can cast this to an int which is what I've shown:

```
In [19]:

df['viewed'] = (df.groupby('user_id')['video_views'].transform('sum') > 0).astype(int)
df
Out[19]:
          date  user_id            session_id  video_views  viewed
0   2015-01-01        1  ZzwDgWjzGAUzEDxazfYL            3       1
1   2015-01-01        2  bH6sC43TrWX5GR85Y3Qc            0       0
2   2015-01-01        3  FY4zGauPwrfpvezreV7b            2       1
3   2015-01-01        4  uNwkvSMkz2kTNcYdjUXu            0       0
4   2015-01-02        1  TGPuDh5LxAN5chuKH7yZ            0       1
5   2015-01-02        2  FQVgJuKGuRnkMDaXFFLC            0       0
6   2015-01-02        3  ubDSttTCGvGrJnN4Kerk            3       1
7   2015-01-02        4  zqrkkm8rNb6dfXyVxEYV            0       0
8   2015-01-03        1  aCTpmLG7vfD6saq6P7Tv            1       1
9   2015-01-03        2  F9UYUjnVgW9XMGzYUvRu            0       0
10  2015-01-03        3  RcmF6Rjk3NVyrejjhhDy            0       1
11  2015-01-03        4  Fy9bw2xTxLpLRTP7TCV9            0       0
```

Just to demonstrate the boolean result:

```
In [20]:

df['viewed'] = df.groupby('user_id')['video_views'].transform('sum') > 0
df
Out[20]:
          date  user_id            session_id  video_views viewed
0   2015-01-01        1  ZzwDgWjzGAUzEDxazfYL            3   True
1   2015-01-01        2  bH6sC43TrWX5GR85Y3Qc            0  False
2   2015-01-01        3  FY4zGauPwrfpvezreV7b            2   True
3   2015-01-01        4  uNwkvSMkz2kTNcYdjUXu            0  False
4   2015-01-02        1  TGPuDh5LxAN5chuKH7yZ            0   True
5   2015-01-02        2  FQVgJuKGuRnkMDaXFFLC            0  False
6   2015-01-02        3  ubDSttTCGvGrJnN4Kerk            3   True
7   2015-01-02        4  zqrkkm8rNb6dfXyVxEYV            0  False
8   2015-01-03        1  aCTpmLG7vfD6saq6P7Tv            1   True
9   2015-01-03        2  F9UYUjnVgW9XMGzYUvRu            0  False
10  2015-01-03        3  RcmF6Rjk3NVyrejjhhDy            0   True
11  2015-01-03        4  Fy9bw2xTxLpLRTP7TCV9            0  False
```